# 500 Internal Server Error while trying to get series data using flux query language

Tags: influxdb

I'm using influxdb using `influx -type=flux`.

I have enabled flux in influxdb.conf file in /etc/influxdb. But as i run a query i get this error

```
from(bucket:"aayush_test/awesome_policy")
Error: unknown server error: 500 Internal Server Error
```

I'm using `influxdb version 1.7.8`. Please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

I got same error.

```
> from (bucket:"someDB/someRP")
Error: unknown server error: 500 Internal Server Error
```

However, if range and measurement is specified in the query then I got back data from InfluxDB 1.7.10.

```
> from (bucket:"someDB/someRP") |> range(start: -10d) |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "someMeasurement")
...
```

As per [Flux](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.50/introduction/getting-started/query-influxdb) documentation, every Flux query needs the following:

1. A data source
2. A time range
3. Data filters

Comment: so... everything needs to be in a single line. Good to know.